# How to use mongoose function inside of loop in JS

Tags: node.js

I am using 'request-promise' module to get the data from some API.
And this gives array value as body.
I want to save that array as each document at mongoDB.
Therefore, I made that with 'for' as loop. 
But when I check this with console.log, 
I hoped like below.

```
Current i is : 0
orderFind
Current i is : 1
orderFind
Current i is : 2
orderFind
Current i is : 3
orderFind
```

However it gives me

```
Current i is : 0
Current i is : 1
Current i is : 2
Current i is : 3
orderFind
orderFind
orderFind
orderFind
```

I tried async, await also. But it doesn't work well..

```
exports.saveOrder = (req, res) => {
  rp({
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://robot.com",
    json: true
  }).then(body => {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(`Current i is : ${i}`);
      const eachBody = body[i];

      Order.findOne(
        {
          order_id: eachBody.order_id
        },
        (err, exOrder) => {
          console.log("orderFind");
          if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to have the log is this order ? It will not change the result of your findOne

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Promise** with `async` and `await`

```
exports.saveOrder = (req, res) => {
  rp({
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://robot.com",
    json: true
  }).then(async body => {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(`Current i is : ${i}`);
      const eachBody = body[i];
      const { order, err } = await findOrder(eachBody);
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      console.log("Order found:", order._id);
    }
  });
};

function findOrder() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Order.findOne(
      {
        order_id: eachBody.order_id
      },
      (err, exOrder) => {
        resolve({
          order: exOrder,
          err
        });
      }
    );
  });
}
```

If you want to get more details about async/await and promises, and potentially executes multiples request asynchronously, I recommend you to check
[this article](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, using `async/await` you can solve the issue

```
exports.saveOrder = (req, res) => {
  rp({
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://robot.com",
    json: true
  }).then(async body => {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(`Current i is : ${i}`);
      const eachBody = body[i];
      try {
        const result = await Order.findOne({ order_id: eachBody.order_id });
        console.log(result);
      } catch (e) {
        return res.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
};
```